# asp c# gridview bind to datatable custom look

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview which i bind to a datatable.
After i bind i want to customize the gridview look, but the columns appear to be null.
I see the data on the page so it is there,
 but when i write  `GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;`
I get an exception: `index out of range`.

how do i customize it?

Comment: Where you are tying to set this GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false ?

Comment: Could you post more code, which we need to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know where you set the column to `Visible = false`

But its right place is in the `Databound Event of Gridview`

```
 protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (GridView1.Columns.Count > 0)
    {
        GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Yuval; Edit my answer. Try now.

Comment: Does your gridview contains data ? This condition only work when your gridview have data.

Comment: i bind it to datatable and after that i try to hide column 1 and i get the exception

Answer (score 0):

**EDITED**

```
   protected void GridView1_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false;
            }
            catch
            {
            }
        }
```

*I don't know why you do that , but you can customize the grid view through this event.*

Take a look at this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/30b7ed89-2ae1-451f-922a-b82078129a0c).

Comment: this will hide the row.. i want to hide the column and to change the look

Comment: i do this code when a button is clicked. i want to do  GridView1.Columns[0].Visible = false; next but i get exception.                                                           DataRow workRow = table1.NewRow();
        workRow["Field"] = FieldsDL.SelectedItem;
        workRow["FieldIndex"] = FieldsDL.SelectedValue;
        table1.Rows.Add(workRow);
      
        ViewState["table"] = table1;
        GridView1.DataSource = table1;

      //  GridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        GridView1.DataBind();

Comment: @Yuval, when you say "change the look" I think CSS, what are you really referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I’ve been through the same issue and I found the workaround on this website
http://ramanisandeep.net/2009/04/07/how-to-hide-gridview-column-programmatically/

Check the else clause.

Basically you go through the header row of the wanted column and each cell of the wanted column and set visibility to false.

I’m not sure if it’s the most recommended way but after looking for a solution for some time, I’m glad with it and will use it.

Good luck,